# Dynamically create Auto-Renewable Subscription

Tags: ios, subscription, auto-renewable

Our app was rejected in App Store because we were using 3rd party solution for subscription and was decided to use In-App Purchases ( Auto-Renewable Subscriptions). I went through several tutorials and it seems that the subscription has to be created in App Store Connect and only then it will be available to use in app and that's the problem for us.

Our app is something like news app where user can subscribe to some author. List of authors comes from server therefore hardcode every subscription for each author is not the way to go.

So, Is that possible to somehow implement what I want with In-App Purchases? Thanks.

Comment: What solution did you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dynamic Auto-Renewable Subscriptions creation (and dynamic in-app purchase creation in general) is not possible. Alternatives would be to sell credits to authors (but this is non-auto renewable). Another possibility is to sell tiers of subscriptions that grant access to a number of authors.

Comment: So it's better to sell some sort of tokens(Consumable in-app purchase) and by that tokens user can buy subscription to author?

Comment: I can't say whether that is better for your flow or not. You will need to determine the pros and cons of any implementation. I was just trying to show some alternative approaches given that dynamic IAP creation is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

There is no option to create subscription dynamically. Your case is a draw back of iOS subscription platform. I have pointed out this problem to Apple subscription team but they were not ready to accept this and forced us to implement in-app subscription, so we had to restrict the number of subscription in app.

Only possible option is to create a number of subscription groups, lets say 10 groups representing each author.

> authorSusbcription1,authorSusbcription2,...authorSusbcription10

I know it's not a viable solution since the number of authors is indefinite. But we don't have any option as of now. You can restrict 10 authors subscription in the app and then prompt users to buy from website if it's exceeds 10.You can show some alert that doesn't violate the in-app rule. For example, "Further subscription is not available in this app" instead of mentioning about your website. Track this user and use an API to send an email to this user asking to subscribe via website.

Unless Apple fix this drawback, we have no other options..!

Comment: Thanks for your response @Abhijith. I've already implemented exactly as you described above. It's pity that Apple don't allow to do that in right way.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out to Apple

Comment: Still having this limitation?